# How to find items in one list that are present in another list?

Tags: c#, linq

List1 and List2 are the 2 lists which I have, expected output should look like list 3, How can I use LINQ in c# to achieve this.

```
Input List1 = {"test1", "test2","test3"};
Input List2 = {{"name": "test1", "value":1},{"name": "test2", "value":2},{"name": "test5", "value":5}};

Output List3 = {{"name": "test1", "value":1},{"name": "test2", "value":2}};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a join:

```
var query = from name in list1
            join item in list2
            on name equals item.name
            select item;

var list3 = query.ToList();
```

This approach would be efficicient if the lists are large.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, you want items from `List2` which names are in the `List1`. If it's your problem, then you can try `Where` with `Contains` something like this:

```
var List3 = List2
  .Where(item => List1.Contains(item.name))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, but it would be faster to convert List1 to a HashSet unless the list is very short.